# YouTube Fancybox not loading the video

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've setup a PHP video browser on a website (check videos pod) when a video thumbnail is clicked a video should popup and play with the FancyBox script, but instead the video just does not load. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using fancybox v2.x with options for fancybox v1.3.x (they are not compatible with each other.)

Your best bet is to get rid of this script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".videobox").click(function () {
        $.fancybox({
            'padding': 0,
            'autoScale': false,
            'transitionIn': 'none',
            'transitionOut': 'none',
            'title': this.title,
            'width': 680,
            'height': 495,
            'href': this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            'type': 'swf',
            'swf': {
                'wmode': 'transparent',
                'allowfullscreen': 'true'
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

and try this instead :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".videobox").fancybox({
            width: 680,
            height: 495,
            type: "iframe"
        }); // fancybox
    }); // ready
</script>
```

notice that we are using `type : "iframe"` because you are using youtube `embed` mode

**SIDE NOTE**: You are loading two versions of jQuery (1.7.1 and 1.7.2) when you actually need a single instance (ideally the latest version) to avoid unexpected errors.